# Why are changes indicated by Git after copying a repo between Windows and Linux machines?

Tags: git, ubuntu, winscp

I have a project repository on a server with no access to internet. I used WinSCP to transfer that repository to my windows machine and then do a pull and push to GitHub.
In this moment, when I execute "git status", everything is clean and up-to-date.
Then, I copied this repository back to the Ubuntu machine using WinSCP using the following setting:

[image]

when I run "git status" on the Ubuntu machine. I see that 6 files are modified in the working directory and are waiting for being added to staging area!!

How it is possible that a repository that is clean on Windows, is not clean on Ubuntu? Can it be related to line ending? if yes, why it happened only for 6 out of 50 files?

Comment: What are the changes? Could be just whitespace characters due to disparate encoding or whatever. Hard to say exactly what without a room with a view, so to speak.

Comment: What actual problem are you trying to solve? I'd probably just reset those files and move on.

Answer (score 1):

Set the `autocrlf` to the desired value:

**How `autocrlf` works**:

```
core.autocrlf=true:    core.autocrlf=input:      core.autocrlf=false:
                                           
       repo                     repo                    repo
    /        \               /        \              /        \
crlf->lf    lf->crlf     crlf->lf       \          /            \      
 /              \        /                \      /                \
```

**Yet another way to show how `autocrlf` works**

```
1) true:             x -> LF -> CRLF
2) input:            x -> LF -> LF
3) false:            x -> x -> x
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @isherwood. I just checked git config and I realized that line endings are not managed automatically by git.

Thus, I ran the following command and now the problem is solved:

```
git config --global core.autocrlf true
```

Comment: I recommend *not* using autocrlf. That tells Git to guess which files are binary and which ones are text. Git will *usually* guess right, but do you let your dog drive your car because he *usually* guesses right about the turns to make? :-)

Comment: If I do not use autocrlf, then what should I use to solve my problem?

Comment: The `.gitattributes` file, which works similarly to the `.gitignore` file, gives you a way to list any special working tree modifications you want made to each file, based on the file's name. So `*.sh` can be set to be `eol=lf`, while `*.bat` is set to be `eol=crlf`, for instance.